# Does questions related to Tasker considered as out of topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Questions about solving problems with [Tasker](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/) like:

- How can I achieve *this* with Tasker?
- Tasker does *that* instead of this.
- How can I use this Action? etc.

Are these questions considered as out of topic for Android Enthusiasts?

I am trying to be neutral while asking this question as a end user of Tasker, I sometimes find myself tempting to ask such questions, but also feel this site might look like a Q&A site for tasker, if such questions are supported - really confused between these two.

Comment: I think the danger with your first and third questions, is that it sounds like you've already settled on a solution (it's almost an XY problem), but people might want to give you non-Tasker answers. Eg question: "How can I get Tasker to switch on the foobar system when flibble happens?" someone might answer with "Use Flibble Foobar Switcher, it's much simpler and does the job well". Which could well be a correct answer to your problem, just not a correct answer to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see how questions as in your examples could be off topic. All of them fit the scope as defined in our [FAQ](https://android.stackexchange.com/faq). None of them matches the kind of questions mentioned as explicitly off topic or "not to be asked".

Question 2 & 3 should be perfectly fine, and I can find no argument defining them off topic. With question 1 one *could* argue it *might* be a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/156683), so here it might be a question of phrasing and interpretation: is it the *problem* you want to solve (and Tasker being your *proposed solution*) -- or is your question rather to understand how one could use Tasker in this context. The latter, again, should be perfectly fine.